# Check if field has certain link written in it

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I am looking for a script to check if a field has these written in it:

- It must have http://
- It must have either steamcommunity or op.gg in the línk.

It needs to check for these before the form is submitted. If it was after, I could do it in PHP, but I want to do it in JavaScript or something before the form is sent.

```
Link to your profile: 
<input type="text" id="profile" name="profile" maxlength="70"><br>
```

For validation I am using JavaScript from [javascript-coder](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) but I don't see how to configure it to check for custom strings.

Comment: on the link you've provided there is a section called 'Adding a custom validation'. That should give you the hint!

Comment: Questions seeking script/library recommendations are not on topic here. It is generally better to either search for a library using a search engine, or make a start on the script and ask for help if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkURL(str) {
    if(str.indexOf("http://") > -1 && (str.indexOf("steamcommunity") > -1 || str.indexOf("op.gg") > -1))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You have the `input` element

```
<input type="text" id="profile" name="profile" maxlength="70">
```

You take its value and then use call the function:

```
var s = document.getElementById('profile').value;
if(!checkURL(s)) {
    //it's not valid, do stuff
}
else {
    //it's valid
}
```

Comment: sorry for the noob question but how do I use that in my form?

Comment: You just call the function wherever you want, if it returns `false`, the value is invalid otherwise valid. See the edit..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
var input = <the text from the input field>
var regex = /^http:\/\/(\w+\.)*(steamcommunity.\w+|op\.gg)\//
if (input.match(regex)) {
  // Accept the input
}
```

[Here's a page](https://regex101.com/r/rX4pS4/1) where you can test that this regex filters out unwanted input